# Share mount namespace with a privileged pod

Tags: namespaces, kubernetes, mount, s3fs

I am trying to get the mount point details of host from a kuberentes pod. It is a privileged container.
Even if I mount the root file system , I am not able to check the mount details of a particular type say `s3fs`may be because it belongs to a different namespace.
What is the best way to share the mount point namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found that kubernetes provides an option called `MountPropagation` which helps to achieve my requirement.

I tested this feature in my local set up and it did give me the result I wanted.

Few links that I found useful:

https://medium.com/kokster/kubernetes-mount-propagation-5306c36a4a2d
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want details of the host's mount points rather than access to them you can run your Pod with `hostPID: true` and then inspect the mounts of a process in the `proc` filesystem that you know is running in the host's mount namespace (for example PID 1) like so: `cat /proc/1/mounts`